# What are these mysterious spike after the FIR filter?

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, gnuradio

The main paramter of this fir filter in flowgraph:

1. Decimation：1
2. Cutoff freq:8KHz
3. Transition width: 1KHz

I have a very simple FIR test in Gnuradio ,the flowgraph is below:
[image: just a cos signal pass a LF filter]

When I change the signal frequency ,there is a moving spike
[image: this is a normal signal spike]

But when the signal is in stop band of the fir filter,there are multiple spike in the spectrum:
You can see there three minor spike on left of the 12.4KHz signal spike.Why??
Can anyone can explain the myth?
[image]

This the whole process while I'm changing the signal frequency:
And you can see the filter frequency response by max hold
[image]

This is the situation using Kaiser window (default Blackman-Harris window)
[image]

Comment: Interesting-- when does it first show  up as you transition from passband to stopband? What do you see when you are right at the edge of the passband  and how do the tones move as you move through the stopband?

Comment: It looks like it's there in the first picture, too. I suspect it's some non-linearity related to the frequency of the tone.  The spacing is larger when the tone is higher in frequency in the second picture.

Comment: Gnuradio's signal source uses a fixed point NCO - aren't these spurs therefore expected? I would normally use some phase dithering on the NCO to handle these, i.e. to improve your SFDR (just dont add too much dithering that you blow up the noise floor!).

Comment: @Dan Boschen ,I have attached the whole signal changing process gif picture.There is very small spike while signal in the passband,after it enters the stopband,there are several big spikes.

Comment: @user67081 ,maybe this is about SFDR,I'll check it!Thanks

Comment: That’s really cool- how did you do the animation? Can you window your tone first (I suggest a Kaiser window) that will keep the floor more consistent and then the same animation will be interesting

Comment: @Dan Boschen,  gnuradio QT GUI Frequency Sink, add a Blackman_Harris window ，I change it to Kaiser window ,it keeps the floor core consistent ,but the spiks are still there.FYI,I use [link](https://www.screentogif.com/) recording the gif,it's free.

Comment: Have you already tried putting the sink right at the source (to see if it is originating there rather than being created in the subsequent blocks)?

Comment: And with the Kaiser window I was thinking a much larger beta (perhaps as high as 23) to see the lower spur levels